# Add an existing ASP.NET Website to Subversion using AnkhSVN/Tortoise

Tags: asp.net, svn, web, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

How do you add a existing ASP.NET website to Subversion dealing with the problems that Subversion dosent support multiple folder structures in the repository:

An default ASP.NET Website Solution folder structure look like this:
C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WebSite1\

WebSite1.sln

WebSite1.suo

C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1\

App_Data

Default.aspx

web.config

How do i import the website to the repository?
How do i get working copys of the website from the repository?
How do i branch the website?
How do i merge the websitebranch into the trunk?

Comment: Not exactly a solution but this "spreading of resources" is one of the reasons I dislike "Web Site" projects. I rather use "Web Application" projects where resources are kept in "one place" and you get a project file (.csproj).

I do not fully understand "...problems that Subversion dosent support multiple folder structures in the repository..." though. What do you mean by that?

Comment: On Adding and Checkout AnkhSVN currently only handles projects in a single tree, just like all other Subversion clients ( like Tortoise).

Comment: I see. Would be nice if Ankh was able to handle this... Never noticed this yet.

Comment: The projects have to be in a single tree in the repository, they do not have to be stored like that on your file system, you just check out different bits of the repo to different parts of the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your files whereever you like in your file system you do not have to accept visual studio defaults.  Also subversion would cope just fine with that file structure, it does not care where they are so long as you can define a common root in the repo to store the files.  You don't even have to store them like that locally, you can check out different bits of a repo to completely differnt areas of the file system.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain in detail how to add an existing website to a subversion repository, wich folder structure you use and how you branch and merge the solution.